# Bash get last sentence in line

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

assume, we got the following variable containing a string:

`text="All of this is one line. But it consists of multiple sentences. Those are separated by dots. I'd like to get this sentence."`

I now need the last sentence "I'd like to get this sentence.". I tried using sed:

`echo "$text" | sed 's/.*\.*\.//'`

I thought it would delete everything up to the pattern `.*.`. It doesn't.

What's the issue here? I'm sure this can be resolved rather fast, unfortunatly I did not find any solution for this.

Comment: What would the expected output be if the last sentence was `The value of pi is 3.14.`? What if the sentence ended in some other punctuation mark like `!`?

Comment: In this case the accepted answer indeed would not work. One possibility could be to include the common space after the dot as separator, so `. `. However this does not apply to my case so I'm going with anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk -F '\\. *' '{print $(NF-1) "."}' <<< "$text"

I'd like to get this sentence.
```

Using sed:

```
sed -E 's/.*\.([^.]+\.)$/\1/' <<< "$text"

 I'd like to get this sentence.
```

Comment: Totally forgot one could change the delimiter of awk. I'm always fixated on the spaces as default. Thanks! Awk is definitely nicer and I actually understand what happens!

Comment: well, for exactly matching the output, should be `awk -F'[.] *' '{print $(NF-1)"." }'`  Trim initial space and add a period.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the built-in

```
echo "${text##*. }"
```

This requires a space after the full stop, but the pattern is easy to adapt if you don't want that.

As for your failed attempt, the regex looks okay, but weird. The pattern `\.*\.` looks for zero or more literal periods followed by a literal period, i.e. effectively one or more period characters.